# How to install GNU Octave on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: 18.10, octave

While trying to install it from Ubuntu Software Store it shows the error "unmet dependencies". I just upgraded from 18.04 LTS which had Octave installed and now I can't use it anymore.

Comment: What are the unmet dependencies? Was `octave` previously installed from a PPA? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy octave`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)